# Elastic Search query to check if all array elements exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new elastic search. I'm using ES for storing candidate details. Each candidate have multiple skills in array.

I want to search candidates by skills.

- If I query for skills as 'Skill - 1' then all candidates with only 'Skill 1' should be returned.
- If I query for skills as 'Skill - 1' and 'Skill - 2' then all candidates with only 'Skill 1' and 'Skill 2' should be returned.

How can I write ES query for above scenario. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a sample document and expected result

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
        "terms_set": {
            "skills" : {
                "terms" : ["Skill1", "Skill2"],
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                   "source": "Math.max(params.num_terms, doc['skills'].length)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```